# Django App Not Reflecting the Changes in Files

Tags: python, django

I have a droplet on Digitalocean that runs Django. Whenever I make any changes on `urls.py` or `views.py`, I need to reboot the server in order to apply those changes in production. Is there any alternative method? Like if I delete the content of **pycache** directory, will it work? I tried `touch` commands but that didn't work.

Comment: If you are in production and not locally then you have to restart your server daemon processes each time you push code to the server.